# Calling incrementer from a for in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, increment, getelementsbytagname

I'm having a bit of trouble calling the incrementer i in this loop in order to identify my current element. Firebug gives me the error `"li[i].addEventListener is not a function"`.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

for(var i in li){
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('yey');
    });
    }
});
```

The strange thing is if I call

```
alert(li[i].getAttribute('id')
```

I get the id alerted to me, but if I then use

```
var id=li[i].getAttribute('id');
document.getElementById(id).addEventListener(blah);
```

I get the same "is not a function" error. Is this a for in loop thing? I noticed that `alert(i);` called some extra stuff at the end of the loop, so is there a different way to use the incrementer in a for in loop? By the way the list I am using is thus:

```
<ul>
    <li id=pomp>
        stuff
    </li>
    <li id=and>
        and
    </li>
    <li id=circumstance>
        things
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is why you have to avoid using `for in` loop

```
for(var i=0;i<li.length;i++){
    li[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('yey');
    });
}
```

when you use for in, `i` is not an integer like you expect, instead it is a property of the nodelist.

Answer (score 0):

As @lbu has pointed out, you should be using `for (decl; test; inc)` to iterate through an array.

However this is also a good place to use *delegation*, since every `<li>` must be a direct descendent of a `<ul>`, you can put the event handlers there instead, and give your browser less work to do:

```
var ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');

for (var i = 0, n = ul.length; i < n; ++i) {
    ul[i].addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        alert(ev.target.id);
    });
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2mk3w/

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way

```
for(var i in li){
    i.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('yey');
    });
    }
});
```

Comment: That would be really cool if it worked like that, but unfortunately this doesn't work.